# How can I set the font and line spacing on HTML I load into a webview?

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview, format

I have an iOS app that parses articles from a remote rss feed.

When I format it through a webview and "LoadHTMLString:withURL," the text is formatted with some default font/line spacing. I want to set my own font/line spacing, and I think that this can be done if I include the correct HTML formatting code as a string in the beginning of each article.

This way I'll manipulate XCode to format the string for my liking.

The only thing is that when I add the line

```
<p style="font: 20pt/30pt Times New Roman, serif;">
```

The text still remains unformatted. I feel like this might be because it creates a nil paragraph which is formatted, but is also nil, so there is no detectable change.

Comment: why not using font-family and font-size instead of font tag? font tag is out off date!

Answer (score 2):

The code set a paragraph in a paragraph so it didn't work, but if you set it up as

```
     NSMutableString *htmlString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"<div style=\"font: 20pt/30pt Times New Roman, serif;\">%@</div>", textFile ];
```

instead, it works fine.