# How to change the line spacing of the text in UIWebView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, spacing

I am having a `UIWebView` which has a certain paragraph in it. I wanted to set the line spacing between the lines of that paragraph. Can anyone help me with this...?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Are you loading html string in webview or a weburl?

Comment: I am loading an html string...

Comment: Check if this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14359339/how-can-i-set-the-font-and-line-spacing-on-html-i-load-into-a-webview

You need to append elements on your side or get that changed in html string that you are getting.

Comment: You could always load in `<style>*Your css for line spacing*</style>` and append your html string at the end of that to "inject" css into the`UIWebView`

Comment: @D.M Please check my answer

Comment: ok..I'll check..

Comment: @D.M is my answer helpful for you?

Comment: It seems no....

Comment: @D.M have you solved the issues?

Comment: @Saurabh Jain Actually I got stuck in something else...Need to look into it later on...Thanks for asking..

Comment: @D.M My pleasure

Answer (score 1):

You have to add javascript code for line spacing into the `UIWebView's` source by calling this

```
func stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from script: String) -> String?

For Example:
        let JSString = //A javascript code for line spacing
        webview.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from:JSString)
```